# Change indent level of page

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I would like to know if and how it's possible to update / change the indent level of a page within a section. I could not find anything about this in the docs of the graph api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by sending the following patch request:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/onenote/pages/<pageid> HTTP/1.1
Authorization: <bearer token>
User-Agent: Java-Client
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json, text/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14

{"level": "1"}
```